# input and result not appending to dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import hashlib
running = True
count = 0
while running:
    saved_hashes = {'input_str': [], 'md5hash': []}
    if count == 1:
        show_q = input('Show other str/hashes? [Y/N]')
        show_q.lower()
        if show_q == 'y':
            print(saved_hashes)
    str_input = input('Enter a string: ')
    str_hash_obj = hashlib.md5(str_input.encode())
    str_to_md5_hash = str_hash_obj.hexdigest()

    print(f'Hash {str_to_md5_hash}')
    saved_hashes['input_str'].extend(str_input)
    saved_hashes['md5hash'].extend(str_to_md5_hash)
    run_choice = input('Again? [Y/N]')
    run_choice.lower()
    if run_choice == 'y':
        count += 1
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Here is the code. I'm still pretty new to Python so I have no idea why the input and result are not being appended.

Comment: What behavior are you expecting and what is currently happening? Just eyeballing it, `extend` should probably be `append`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to create a `list` of dictionaries. Create an empty list before the `while` loop, then `append` the dictionary to the list within the loop:

```
import hashlib
running = True
count = 0

saved_hashes = []
while running:
    if count == 1:
        show_q = input('Show other str/hashes? [Y/N]')
        show_q.lower()
        if show_q == 'y':
            print(saved_hashes)
    str_input = input('Enter a string: ')
    str_hash_obj = hashlib.md5(str_input.encode())
    str_to_md5_hash = str_hash_obj.hexdigest()

    print(f'Hash {str_to_md5_hash}')
    saved_hashes.append({'input_str': [str_input], 'md5hash': [str_to_md5_hash]})
    run_choice = input('Again? [Y/N]')
    run_choice.lower()
    if run_choice == 'y':
        count += 1
        continue
    else:
        break
```